# jenkins:used git plugin ,system error 'java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: '

Tags: jenkins

I have download Credentials plugin and added Credentials in Credentials module.

[image: credentials screenshot]

[image: error message screenshot]

system error is

> javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.track(Lhudson/model/Item;Lcom/cloudbees/plugins/credentials/Credentials;)Lcom/cloudbees/plugins/credentials/Credentials;

Answer (score 0):

Prevent setting SecurityContext to null

https://github.com/jenkinsci/credentials-plugin/commit/b0f83a77d238775f709f5bda7a526ecd56e7d9af  this will may help you!

Comment: can you explain how to use this script? i just learned to use jenkins, do not know how to do ,thanks very much.